# How to implement retweet functionality in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to implement retweet functionality on my app.

So I have my retweet_id in my tweets model

#### tweets schema

```
| user_id | content | created_at | updated_at | retweet_id
```

#### tweets.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :retweets, class_name: 'Tweet', foreign_key: 'retweet_id'
```

#### user.rb

```
has_many :tweets
```

And in my tweets controller

#### tweets_controller.rb

```
    ...


def retweet
    @retweet = Tweet.new(retweet_params)
      if @retweet.save
        redirect_to tweet_path, alert: 'Retweeted!'
      else
        redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Can not retweet'
      end
    end
    
    Private
    ...
    def retweet_params
      params.require(:retweet).permit(:retweet_id, :content).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
```

In my view

#### tweets/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Retweet', retweet_tweet_path(@tweet.id), method: :post %>
```

My routes

```
resources :tweets do
  resources :comments
  resources :likes
  member do
    post :retweet
  end
end
```

So when I try this I get an error

```
param is missing or the value is empty: retweet
```

So I remove .require from 'retweet_params' and that removes that error (though i'm unsure of how wise that is)

Then the link works but won't retweet - reverting to the fallback root_path specified in my action instead.

```
Unpermitted parameters: :_method, :authenticity_token, :id
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. How can I get my retweets working? ty

Comment: Does your `Tweet` model include `validates :content, presence: true`? (i.e., must each tweet have content?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `retweet_params` raises an error is because your link `link_to 'Retweet', retweet_tweet_path(@tweet.id), method: :post` doesn't contain parameters like a new or edit form does. Instead you should create a new tweet that reference to tweet you want to retweet.

```
before_action :set_tweet, only: %i[show edit update destroy retweet]

def retweet
  retweet = @tweet.retweets.build(user: current_user)
  if retweet.save
    redirect_to retweet, notice: 'Retweeted!'
  else
    redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Can not retweet'
  end
end

private

def set_tweet
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
end
```

The above should automatically link the new tweet to the "parent". If this doesn't work for some reason you could manually set it by changing the above to:

```
retrweet = Tweet.new(retweet_id: @tweet.id, user: current_user)
```

The above approach doesn't save any content, since this is a retweet.

If you don't want to allow multiple retweets of the same tweet by the same user, make sure you have the appropriate constraints and validations set.

```
# migration
add_index :tweets, %i[user_id retweet_id], unique: true

# model
validates :retweet_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

---

How do we access the content of a retweet? The answer is we get the content form the parent or source (however you want to call it).

There is currently no association that lets you access the parent or source tweet. You currently already have:

> ```
> has_many :retweets, class_name: 'Tweet', foreign_key: 'retweet_id'
> ```

To easily access the source content let's first add an additional association.

```
belongs_to :source_tweet, optional: true, inverse_of: :retweets, class_name: 'Tweet', foreign_key: 'retweet_id'
has_many :retweets, inverse_of: :source_tweet, class_name: 'Tweet', foreign_key: 'retweet_id'
```

With the above associations being set we can override the `content` getter and setter of the `Tweet` model.

```
def content
  if source_tweet
    source_tweet.content
  else
    super
  end
end

def content=(content)
  if source_tweet
    raise 'retweets cannot have content'
  else
    super
  end
end

# depending on preference the setter could also be written as validation
validates :content, absence: true, if: :source_tweet
```

Note that the above is not efficient when talking about query speed, but it's the easiest most clear solution. Solving parent/child queries is sufficiently difficult that it should get its own question, if speed becomes an issue.

If you are wondering why I set the `inverse_of` option. I would recommend you to check out the section [Active Record Associations - 3.5 Bi-directional Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations).

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't work, the link works but the retweet_id is not saving and it keeps sending back to root. (I presume you mean @retweet = @tweet.retweets...) ? Otherwise error is undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @davidm That was indeed a typo. They should both be `retweet` or both be `@retweet`, but not different from each other. The reason you'll receive the error is probably because you have a validation that requires `content` to be present. You can copy over the content from `@tweet` or update the validation to something like `validates :content, presence: true, unless: :retweet_id?` This allows an empty content if the tweet is a retweet.

Comment: Ah now it works. Thanks! Oh just one last thing (hope you don't mind) - how in the view would I retrieve the content from the original tweet to show in the timeline of the user that retweeted it? (currently it's missing) Any little guidance at all there would be fab!

Comment: @davidm I've updated the the answer with additional info on how to easily get the the content of a retweet.

Comment: wow, thanks, works for the content. I take it this will work for the user handle of the original tweet, or name...etc for example? Speed is not a big deal at the moment, it's a personal project but if it became an issue i'd ask a new question. Thanks a lot! Learned a lot there.

Comment: Did def username if source_tweet source_tweet.user.username... and then in the view <%= tweet.username %> and works too! Brilliant :)

Comment: @davidm Glad the answer is of use. The current answer does allow a user to retweet a retweet, or retweet their own tweet. You could add validations for those, but I left that out of the answer to prevent the answer from getting to big. The behaviour is also subjectively good or bad, depending on what you want/expect.

Answer (score 2):

Right now the error you're seeing is the one for strong params in Rails. If you can check your debugger or the HTTP post request that's being sent, you'd find that you don't have the params that you're "requiring" in `retweet_params`

```
def retweet_params
  params.require(:retweet).permit(:retweet_id, :content).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

This is essentially saying that you expect a nested hash for the params like so

```
params = { retweet: { id: 1, content: 'Tweet' } }
```

This won't work since you're only sending the ID. How about something like this instead?

*TweetsController.rb*

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def retweet
    original_tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])

    @retweet = Tweet.new(
      user_id: current_user.id,
      content: original_tweet.content
    )

    if @retweet.save
      redirect_to tweet_path, alert: 'Retweeted!'
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Can not retweet'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That works. Thank you! But how can I constrain it to one retweet per user because with this method a user can keep retweeting endlessly the same tweet? Your explanation really helpful too.

Comment: @davidm You should also assign the `retweet_id` when you are creating a new tweet. `retweet_id: original_tweet.id`. When you add a unique constraint to the database `add_index :tweets, [:user_id, :retweet_id], unique: true` you can no longer retweet the same tweet multiple times. In addition to the database restriction you could also add a validation `validates :retweet_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }`

Comment: Just FYI, this approach loses data. That is, the `retweet` has no value for `retweet_id`. Also, I wonder if you really want to assign the content from the original tweet to the retweet. Conceptually, the content really belongs to the original tweet, not the retweet.

Comment: @3limin4t0r first thing I noticed was no values in retweet_id. I'm wondering whether this is the correct approach to this at all as it seems like I could end up falling down a rabbit hole here. I have gone back to the start here and will try for a cleaner way.